# How to randomly pick a certain amount of rows in CSV files and keep the others

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Say that I have a thousand rows of data in a csv file, each with 4 columns.

I'd like to randomly pick 950 rows of the data and keep the other 50 rows separately. I will further process these two datasets using python.

How do I do that in an easy way?

I use pandas to read in the csv files by columns.

Comment: Could you show the code your using to import the csv files?

Comment: train_file = "training_data_ez.csv"   
train_features = pd.read_csv(train_file, usecols=['var', 'sq', 'sin'])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
train_file = "training_data_ez.csv" 
train_features = pd.read_csv(train_file, usecols=['var', 'sq', 'sin'])
```

The [`pd.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) method let's you randomly sample from your `pd.DataFrame`. By default this is without replacement, i.e. we don't sample the same row twice.

```
df_950 = train_features.sample(950)
```

The remaining 50 we can just get by `dropping` the 950 rows from our original DataFrame.

```
df_50 = train_features.drop(df_950.index)
```

The [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function from scikit-learn is an alternative, if you need to preserve class-balance in your random samples.

Comment: I just put this method as an alternative to my method as an edit, before I saw that you had already posted it. +1 for not using an external library!

Comment: Thanks! seems like there are quite a few ways of doing it ^_^

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this would be to use [`train_test_split` from `sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), and set the `test_size` to be 0.05 (because 0.05 % of 1000 is 50):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df1, df2 = train_test_split(train_file, test_size=0.05)
```

Then `df1` will be your dataframe of 950 rows, and `df2` will be your dataframe of 50 rows

Answer (score 2):

Another option can be this:

```
import random
r = (random.sample(range(0, 1000), 1000))
df1 = df.iloc[r[0:950]]
df2 = df.iloc[r[950:]]
```